# undefined method `filter_attributes=' for #<ActiveAdmin::Application:0x00007f979d8206b8> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

When I added gem activeadmin_trumbowyg to my application I received below error while staring rails server, is there any solution.

gem file:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.7'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4', '>= 5.2.4.1'

gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'


gem 'dotenv-rails'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.4.3'
gem 'active_skin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin_trumbowyg'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
```

```rb
Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    60: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    59: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    58: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    57: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    56: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    55: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    54: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    53: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    52: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    51: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    50: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
    49: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
    48: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
    47: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    46: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    45: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    44: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    43: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    42: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    41: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    40: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    39: from config.ru:in `new'
    38: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    37: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    36: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    35: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    34: from /Users/anton/Documents/Websites/b/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    32: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    31: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    30: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    29: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    28: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    27: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    26: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    25: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    24: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    23: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
    22: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
    21: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    20: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    19: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    18: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    16: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    15: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    14: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    13: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    12: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
    11: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    10: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
     9: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
     8: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
     7: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
     6: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
     4: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
     3: from /Users/anton/Documents/Websites/b/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin.rb:69:in `setup'
     1: from /Users/anton/Documents/Websites/b/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:172:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:37:in `method_missing': undefined method `filter_attributes=' for #<ActiveAdmin::Application:0x00007f979d8206b8> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: have you done bundle install after updating your gem file?

Comment: Any specific reason not to use the official activeadmin ?

Comment: I think he is trying to integrate trumbowyg editor with the active admin

Comment: @Vishal correct

Comment: Did you follow all the setup steps from https://github.com/blocknotes/activeadmin_trumbowyg ?

Comment: Adding lines to active_admin.scss and active_admin.js

Comment: @Mark, the problem Arieses in active_admin inside initializers (filter_attributes=) may be it isn't supported to active-admin 1.4.3 as I downgrade my version from 2.6.7 for gem activeadmin_trumbowyg